# Set timeout on if true, cancel it on else

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

So, I call this function on a mouse over / mouse out event. First (mouse over) I call it with the  'open' parameter, then (mouse out) with the 'close' parameter.

I wanted to add a delay to the overlay display, and cancel the display of the function is called with 'close' before the timeout expires.

Without the timeout the function enters the 'close' branch instantly on mouse out, with the timeout event it does not run the if until the timeout is over, leaving no chance for `window.clearTimeout(emgOverTimer);` to do its magic.

```js
function emgFluidOverlayShow(action, currentElement) {
    var $overlay = $('#emg-fluid-overlay');

    if (action == 'open') {
        var emgOverTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            $(currentElement).addClass('emg-fluid-bring-front');
            $overlay.addClass('emg-fluid-anim-overlay');
            $overlay.data('statuson', true);
        }, 1000);
    } 
    else if (action == 'close') {
        window.clearTimeout(emgOverTimer);
        console.log(1);
        $overlay.removeClass('emg-fluid-anim-overlay');
        $overlay.data('statuson', false);
        $('.emg-fluid-header').find('.emg-fluid-bring-front').removeClass('emg-fluid-bring-front');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `emgOverTimer` variable is a **local** variable in the function, so naturally on subsequent calls to the function, it's a *different* variable from the one used by the previous call.

Move it out to the containing scope so all the `emgFluidOverlayShow` function calls use the same variable:

```
var emgOverTimer = 0;                                  // <=== Declaration
function emgFluidOverlayShow(action, currentElement) {
  var $overlay = $('#emg-fluid-overlay');

  if (action == 'open') {
   emgOverTimer = setTimeout(function() {              // <=== No `var` here
    $(currentElement).addClass('emg-fluid-bring-front');
    $overlay.addClass('emg-fluid-anim-overlay');
    $overlay.data('statuson', true);
   }, 1000);

  } else if (action == 'close') {
    window.clearTimeout(emgOverTimer);
    console.log(1);
    $overlay.removeClass('emg-fluid-anim-overlay');
    $overlay.data('statuson', false);
    $('.emg-fluid-header').find('.emg-fluid-bring-front').removeClass('emg-fluid-bring-front');
  }
}
```

I would also update the logic to handle the case of multiple `open` calls, by inserting this after `if (action == 'open')`:

```
window.clearTimeout(imgOverTimer);
```

and clearing the timer handle in the the timer callback and also the `close` case as well:

```
imgOverTimer = 0;
```

So all together:

```
var emgOverTimer = 0;
function emgFluidOverlayShow(action, currentElement) {
  var $overlay = $('#emg-fluid-overlay');

  if (action == 'open') {
   window.clearTimeout(emgOverTimer);
   emgOverTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    emgOverTimer = 0;
    $(currentElement).addClass('emg-fluid-bring-front');
    $overlay.addClass('emg-fluid-anim-overlay');
    $overlay.data('statuson', true);
   }, 1000);

  } else if (action == 'close') {
    window.clearTimeout(emgOverTimer);
    emgOverTimer = 0;
    console.log(1);
    $overlay.removeClass('emg-fluid-anim-overlay');
    $overlay.data('statuson', false);
    $('.emg-fluid-header').find('.emg-fluid-bring-front').removeClass('emg-fluid-bring-front');
  }
}
```

**Simplified Live Example:**

```js
// Scoping function so we don't create any globals
(function() {
  "use strict"; // Strict mode is almost always a good idea

  // Handlers to simulate calls to our function
  document.getElementById("btnOpen").onclick = function() {
    emgFluidOverlayShow('open');
  };
  document.getElementById("btnClose").onclick = function() {
    emgFluidOverlayShow('close');
  };
  
  // Timer handle
  var emgOverTimer = 0;
  
  // Function
  function emgFluidOverlayShow(action) {
    if (action == 'open') {
      clearTimeout(emgOverTimer);
      emgOverTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        emgOverTimer = 0;
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "";
      }, 1000);
    } else if (action == 'close') {
      clearTimeout(emgOverTimer);
      emgOverTimer = 0;
        document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
    }
  }

})();
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnOpen" value="Open">
<input type="button" id="btnClose" value="Close">
<div id="overlay" style="display: none">I'm the overlay</div>
```

Note that calling `clearTimeout` with an invalid handle is a no-op, and `0` is by definition an invalid handle, so we don't need guards around the `clearTimeout` calls. (You could add them, of course, if you like.)

---

Side note: Unless your code shadows the `window` variable, there's no technical reason for prefixing `setTimeout` and such with `window.` (You might be doing it for emphasis or similar). `window` and `setTimeout` are both globals, the JavaScript engine has to work as hard to find `window` (e.g., chaining up through all containing scopes) as it does to find `setTimeout` and such.

Comment: Ok, I had a feeling it was a scope problem, thank you, I'll define an object so I don't have to use a global variable :)

Comment: @Ioan-RaduTanasescu: I just said move it out to the containing scope, not to make it a global. :-) If you're worried about globals, your `emgFluidOverlayShow` should *also* not be global. (I do this by putting all of my code inside a scoping function.)

Comment: Oh, so if I assign a variable without the var word, it does not become global, but rather updates in its own scope? Didn't know that, thank you!

Comment: @Ioan-RaduTanasescu: The assignment inside `emgFluidOverlayShow` above assigns to the variable in the nearest containing scope's context. Since you don't have a `emgOverTimer` within `emgFluidOverlayShow` itself, the JavaScript engine looks at the binding object for the containing context -- and because we've declared it there, it finds it there. So if all of the above is inside a scoping function, no globals are created. It's only if a variable is *completed undeclared* that you run into [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: @Ioan-RaduTanasescu: FWIW, I added a simplified live example (with a scoping function).